# Is there any way to get 2 rows from each of the queries?

Tags: mysql, select, limit, inner-join, union

I have the following MYSQL query:

```
SELECT m.id AS id, 'admin' AS type, m.title AS title, m.message AS message, m.link AS link, m.image AS image, 'White' AS colour_scheme
                FROM x_elder_messages m
                UNION
                SELECT a.id AS id, 'evidence' AS type, a.name AS title, a.about AS message, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/view/ambition/',a.id,'/') AS link, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/x_images/x_ambitions/current/thumb/',ai.image_id,'.jpg') AS image, 'White' AS colour_scheme
                FROM x_ambitions a
                INNER JOIN x_ambition_images ai
                ON a.id = ai.ambition_id
                UNION 
                SELECT u.id AS id, 'profile_update' AS type, CONCAT(u.x_first_name,' ',u.x_last_name) AS title, CONCAT(CONCAT(u.x_first_name,' ',u.x_last_name),' has recently updated their profile') AS message, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/view/',u.id,'/') AS link, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/x_images/x_users/current/thumb/',i.image_id,'.jpg') AS image, 'Dark' AS colour_scheme
                FROM x_user u
                INNER JOIN x_user_images i
                ON u.id = i.user_id
                ORDER BY RAND()
```

I have the output to have the same column names, so that I can deal with the result as a whole. But is there any way to LIMIT 2 for each of the queries, so that it would grab 2 admin, 2 ambition, 2 users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put a `limit` in each subquery:

```
(SELECT m.id AS id, 'admin' AS type, m.title AS title, m.message AS message, m.link AS link, m.image AS image, 'White' AS colour_scheme
                FROM x_elder_messages m
 LIMIT 2
) UNION
(SELECT a.id AS id, 'evidence' AS type, a.name AS title, a.about AS message, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/view/ambition/',a.id,'/') AS link, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/x_images/x_ambitions/current/thumb/',ai.image_id,'.jpg') AS image, 'White' AS colour_scheme
                FROM x_ambitions a
                INNER JOIN x_ambition_images ai
                ON a.id = ai.ambition_id
 LIMIT 2
) UNION 
(SELECT u.id AS id, 'profile_update' AS type, CONCAT(u.x_first_name,' ',u.x_last_name) AS title, CONCAT(CONCAT(u.x_first_name,' ',u.x_last_name),' has recently updated their profile') AS message, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/view/',u.id,'/') AS link, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/x_images/x_users/current/thumb/',i.image_id,'.jpg') AS image, 'Dark' AS colour_scheme
                FROM x_user u
                INNER JOIN x_user_images i
                ON u.id = i.user_id
 LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY RAND() ;
```

In addition, you should use `union all` unless you want to intentionally remove duplicates (that adds extra processing).  And when using `limit` you typically want an `order by` to specify which rows you get.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, is there any way also, to randomly shuffle the whole output of the query? Do I simply put an ORDER BY RAND() at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.type, a.title, a.message, a.link, a.image, a.colour_scheme 
FROM (SELECT m.id AS id, 'admin' AS TYPE, m.title AS title, m.message AS message, m.link AS link, m.image AS image, 'White' AS colour_scheme
      FROM x_elder_messages m
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
    ) AS a
UNION
SELECT b.id, b.type, b.title, b.message, b.link, b.image, b.colour_scheme 
FROM (SELECT a.id AS id, 'evidence' AS TYPE, a.name AS title, a.about AS message, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/view/ambition/',a.id,'/') AS link, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/x_images/x_ambitions/current/thumb/',ai.image_id,'.jpg') AS image, 'White' AS colour_scheme
      FROM x_ambitions a
      INNER JOIN x_ambition_images ai ON a.id = ai.ambition_id
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
    ) AS b
UNION 
SELECT c.id, c.type, c.title, c.message, c.link, c.image, c.colour_scheme 
FROM (SELECT u.id AS id, 'profile_update' AS TYPE, CONCAT(u.x_first_name,' ',u.x_last_name) AS title, CONCAT(CONCAT(u.x_first_name,' ',u.x_last_name),' has recently updated their profile') AS message, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/view/',u.id,'/') AS link, CONCAT('http://www.aaa.com/x/x_images/x_users/current/thumb/',i.image_id,'.jpg') AS image, 'Dark' AS colour_scheme
      FROM x_user u
      INNER JOIN x_user_images i ON u.id = i.user_id
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
    ) AS c
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MySQL SQL, but I would suggest restricting each of the subqueries to two rows. On Ms-sqlserver one would use 'top 2' for each select. To be able to differentiate between to subsets add a static value for each. On the first select you could use in the select statement 'type = elder_message'.